# How I can get a Turkish visa to visit Istanbul on a layover?

Tags: transit, turkey, georgia-country, pakistani-citizens, isl

I am flying to Tbilisi, Georgia with Turkish Airline. My stay in Istanbul is 12 hours. Can I get transit visa to visit Istanbul city ?

I am from Pakistan with Oman employment visa.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can, by applying at the Turkish embassy in Muscat.

If you had a Schengen/UK/US/Irish visa or residence permit, you could get an electronic entry permit, which is easier, but because you don't you'll have to apply for a transit visa at the embassy