# 15-hour layover in Istanbul

Tags: transit

I am traveling with Turkish Airlines (return ticket) from Saudi Arabia to Pakistan. Can I visit Istanbul during my layover time (15 hours)? I am a Pakistan national and I have a resident permit of Saudi Arabia.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Could you please add your nationality, as that would determine what type of visa you would need.

Comment: Pakistan National and do have Resident permit of Saudi Arabia

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80848/how-i-can-get-a-turkish-visa-to-visit-istanbul-on-a-layover

Comment: Nope you need to apply for a transit visa.